# Conversión desde el sistema de numeración decimal a otro sistema de numeración (binario, octal, hexadecimal, etc.)

Tags: c#, binario, sistemas-de-numeración, octal, hexadecimal

### **Esta pregunta es autorespondida.**

¿Cómo convertir un número natural desde el sistema de numeración decimal a otro sistema de numeración (**binario**, **octal**, **hexadecimal**, etc.)?

Para ver como convertir de binario, octal y hexadecimal a decimal vea: [Conversión desde los sistemas numéricos binario, octal y hexadecimal al sistema numérico decimal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506199/conversi%c3%b3n-desde-los-sistemas-num%c3%a9ricos-binario-octal-y-hexadecimal-al-sistema/506200#506200)

Comment: ¿Por qué dos preguntas iguales?

Comment: @Mateo no son iguales, esta pregunta es para convertir de decimal a binario, octal o hexadecimal, y la otra pregunta es el proceso inverso, es decir, como convertir de binario, octal, hexadecimal a decimal

Comment: Ah. Gracias por aclararlo. Me resultaron muy similares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un sistema numérico tiene como objetivo permitir el conteo de los elementos de un conjunto. Entre los mas conocidos se encuentran:

**Sistema binario:** Los números se representan utilizando las cifras **0** y **1**, es muy utilizado en informática. Su base es **2**, ya que solo se representa con dos símbolos (**0** y **1**).

**Sistema octal:** Los números se representan utilizando las cifras del **0** al **7**. Su base es **8**, ya que se representa con **8** símbolos.

**Sistema decimal:** Los números se representan utilizando las cifras del **0** al **9**. Es el que utilizan los seres humanos. Su base es **10** ya que se representa con **10** símbolos.

**Sistema hexadecimal:** Los números se representan utilizando las cifras del **0** al **9**, y las letras **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E**, **F**, donde **A = 10**, **B = 11**, **C = 12**, **D = 13**, **E = 14**, **F = 15**. Es muy utilizado en informática. Su base es **16** ya que se representa con **16** símbolos.

Para convertir un número del **sistema decimal** a otro sistema de numeración se divide el número del **sistema decimal** entre la base del sistema de numeración a convertir, cuyo resultado entero (cociente) se vuelve a dividir entre la base, y así sucesivamente hasta que el resultado de la división (cociente) sea menor que la base. Posteriormente se ordena desde el último cociente y resto obtenido hasta el primer resto de todas las divisiones previamente realizadas.

**Ejemplos:**

**1)** Conversión del **sistema decimal** al **sistema binario**:

Supongamos que queremos convertir el número **131** del **sistema decimal** a su representación en **sistema binario**. Atendiendo al algoritmo antes descrito:

**131 / 2 = 65** con resto **1**

**65 / 2 = 32** con resto **1**

**32 / 2 = 16** con resto **0**

**16 / 2 = 8** con resto **0**

**8 / 2 = 4** con resto **0**

**4 / 2 = 2** con resto **0**

**2 / 2 = 1** con resto **0**; ya aquí observamos que el cociente (**1**) es menor que la base (**2**), por tanto paramos e invertimos desde el último cociente y resto hasta el primer resto, obteniendo como resultado: **10000011** y es esta la representación de **131** en el **sistema binario**.

**2)** Conversión del **sistema decimal** al **sistema octal**:

Supongamos que queremos convertir el número **768** del **sistema decimal** a su representación en el **sistema octal**. Atendiendo al algoritmo antes descrito:

**768 / 8 = 96** con resto **0**

**96 / 8 = 12** con resto **0**

**12 / 8 = 1** con resto **4**; ya aquí observamos que el cociente (**1**) es menor que la base (**8**), por tanto paramos e invertimos desde el último cociente y resto hasta el primer resto, obteniendo como resultado: **1400** y es esta la representación de **768** en el **sistema octal**.

**3)** Conversión del **sistema decimal** al **sistema hexadecimal**:

Supongamos que queremos convertir el número **332** del **sistema decimal** a su representación en el **sistema hexadecimal**. Atendiendo al algoritmo antes descrito:

**332 / 16 = 20** con resto **12** (En el **sistema hexadecimal** el **12** se sustituye por la letra **C**)

**20 / 16 = 1** con resto **4**; ya aquí observamos que el cociente (**1**) es menor que la base (**16**), por tanto paramos e invertimos desde el último cociente y resto hasta el primer resto, obteniendo como resultado: **14C** y es esta la representación de **332** en el **sistema hexadecimal**.

Una vez explicado todo lo anterior pasamos al código:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class SistemasNumericos
    {
        static private readonly Dictionary<int, string> numerosPorLetras = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
           {10, "A"},
           {11, "B"},
           {12, "C"},
           {13, "D"},
           {14, "E"},
           {15, "F"}
        };
     
        private static void VerificarBase(Stack<string> numBaseX, int modulo)
        {           
            if (modulo >= 10)
            {
                numBaseX.Push(numerosPorLetras[modulo]);
            }
            else
            {
                numBaseX.Push(modulo.ToString());
            }
        }
       
        static public string ConvertirBase10ToBaseX(int num, int basse)
        {
            Stack<string> numBaseX = new Stack<string>();
            string resultado = "Debe insertar una base entre 2 y 16";
            int modulo = 0;

            if (basse > 1 && basse <= 16)
            {
                resultado = "";

                while (num >= basse)
                {
                    modulo = num % basse;
                    VerificarBase(numBaseX, modulo);
                    num = num / basse;
                }

                VerificarBase(numBaseX, num);

                foreach (var n in numBaseX)
                {
                    resultado += n;
                }
            }

            return resultado;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí declaramos una **clase estática** llamada **SistemasNumericos**, dentro de esta clase se declara un **campo privado** llamado **letrasPorNumeros** de tipo **Dictionary<int, string>**, que representa un tipo de dato **llave/valor**, donde la llave es un número único (no se puede repetir) y el valor asociado a esta llave es un **string**, este diccionario se usará para las conversiones al **sistema hexadecimal**, ya que servirá para sustituir determinados números por su correspondiente letra en la representación del **sistema hexadecimal**.

Después vendría la implementación del **método estático y público ConvertirBase10ToBaseX**, que es el método que nos convertirá cualquier número en el **sistema decimal** a la base que le especifiquemos. Este método recibe dos parámetros enteros que son el número y la base, y retorna un **string** que sería el resultado final. Dentro de este método declaramos un tipo de dato **Stack** (**Pila** en español), la cual nos servirá para ir almacenando cada resto por cada división y el cociente de la última división. Se usa este tipo de datos **Pila** ya que es una estructura de tipo **LIFO** (**Last In First Out / Último en entrar Primero en salir**),
es decir el último elemento que entra sería el primero en salir, de esta forma al finalizar el algoritmo el primer elemento de la **Pila** sería el último cociente, y el último elemento de la **Pila** sería el primer resto obtenido, de esta forma no tenemos que invertir nada ya que la **Pila** al ser una estructura **LIFO** nos ahorraría la inversión.

Después declaramos una **variable entera** llamada **modulo** que servirá para ir guardando el resto de cada división que hagamos, y posteriormente declaramos una variable de tipo **string** llamada **resultado** que guardará la conversión realizada entre los sistemas numéricos, siendo el valor final de esta variable lo que retornará la función. Esta variable se inicializa con un valor por defecto, que es un mensaje en caso de que la conversión no pueda realizarse.

Después de las declaraciones de variables ejecutamos un **condicional if** para asegurarnos que la base introducida se encuentra entre **2** y **16**, en caso de que la base no se encuentre entre estos valores, la función retornará el valor por defecto con que se inicializó la **variable resultado**, indicando que la base no se encuentra en un rango válido. Si la base se encuentra en el rango especificado entonces se procede a realizar la conversión entre los sistemas numéricos,
para ello se ejecuta un **ciclo while** que se ejecutará mientras se cumpla la condición **num >= base**. Este **ciclo while** hará lo que se explicó mas arriba en la descripción del algoritmo, es decir se irá obteniendo el resto de cada división y dividiendo el número por su base hasta que se devuelva un cociente menor que la base indicada.

Aquí se llama a un **procedimiento privado** llamado **VerificarBase**, que recibe dos parámetros, la **Pila** y un número entero (que sería el resto obtenido por cada división) , esta función lo que hace es comprobar si ese número es mayor o igual que **10**, de cumplirse esta condición entonces debemos sustituir este resto por su correspondiente letra en el diccionario previamente declarado, ya que los restos mayores a **9** se representan por letras tal como se explicó anteriormente.

Después del salir del **ciclo while** volvemos a llamar al **procedimiento VerificarBase** para analizar el último cociente de la última división. Posteriormente recorremos la **Pila** con un **foreach** concatenando a la **variable resultado** cada nodo de la **Pila**. Finalmente retornamos el valor de la **variable resultado** con la conversión realizada.

Para hacer uso de la **clase SistemasNumericos** podemos hacer lo siguiente (uso de ejemplo una **aplicación de consola**):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Escriba un número: ");

        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Escriba una base: ");

        int basse = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(SistemasNumericos.ConvertirBase10ToBaseX(num, basse));
        Console.Write("Presione una tecla para terminar:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Introducimos un número y una base, llamamos a la **función ConvertirBase10ToBaseX** de la **clase SistemasNumericos** pasando como parámetros los valores previamente introducidos y finalmente imprimimos el resultado devuelto por esta función.

**Bibliografía:**

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_num%C3%A9rico

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_binario

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_octal

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_hexadecimal