# Conversión desde los sistemas numéricos binario, octal y hexadecimal al sistema numérico decimal

Tags: c#, binario, hexadecimal, octal, sistemas-de-numeración

### **Esta pregunta es autorespondida**

¿Cómo convertir un número expresado en los **sistemas numéricos binario**, **octal** y **hexadecimal** al **sistema numérico decimal**?

Para ver como convertir un número del sistema numérico decimal a los sistemas numéricos binario, octal y hexadecimal vea:
[Conversión desde el sistema de numeración decimal a otro sistema de numeración (binario, octal, hexadecimal, etc.)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/505485/conversi%c3%b3n-desde-el-sistema-de-numeraci%c3%b3n-decimal-a-otro-sistema-de-numeraci%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SistemasNumericos
{
    static private readonly Dictionary<char, int> letrasPorNumeros = new Dictionary<char, int>()
    {
       {'A', 10},
       {'B', 11},
       {'C', 12},
       {'D', 13},
       {'E', 14},
       {'F', 15},
    };
        
    static public int ConvertirBinarioToDecimal(string numero)
    {
        var potencia = 1;
        var numeroDecimal = 0;
        var numeroBinario = 0;
        var binario = numero.Reverse();

        foreach (var n in binario)
        {
            numeroBinario = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString());
            numeroDecimal += numeroBinario * potencia;
            potencia *= 2;
        }

        return numeroDecimal;
    }

    static public int ConvertirOctalToDecimal(string numero)
    {
        var potencia = 1;
        var numeroDecimal = 0;
        var numeroOctal = 0;
        var octal = numero.Reverse();

        foreach (var n in octal)
        {
            numeroOctal = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString());
            numeroDecimal += numeroOctal * potencia;
            potencia *= 8;
        }

        return numeroDecimal;
    }

    static public int ConvertirHexadecimalToDecimal(string numero)
    {
        numero = numero.ToUpper();

        var potencia = 1;
        var numeroDecimal = 0;
        var numeroHexadecimal = 0;
        var hexadecimal = numero.Reverse();

        foreach (var n in hexadecimal)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(n))
            {
                numeroHexadecimal = letrasPorNumeros[n];
            }
            else
            {
                numeroHexadecimal = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString());
            }

            numeroDecimal += numeroHexadecimal * potencia;
            potencia *= 16;
        }

        return numeroDecimal;
    }
}
```

### **Convertir del sistema numérico binario al sistema numérico decimal**

En el **sistema de numeración binario** los números se representan utilizando solamente las cifras **0** y **1**. Para realizar su conversión al **sistema decimal** deberá seguir estos pasos:

**1)** Debe empezar a analizar el **número binario** de derecha a izquierda y multiplicar cada dígito del número binario por 2 elevado a la posición que ocupa ese dígito dentro del **numero binario**, donde el dígito más a la derecha ocupa la posición **0**, el segundo dígito la posición **1**, y así sucesivamente (El orden es de derecha a izquierda).

**2)** Después de realizar todas estas multiplicaciones deberá sumarlas todas y el número obtenido será el equivalente al **sistema decimal**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
110101 (binario)
```

Si analizamos el número de derecha a izquierda, atendiendo al algoritmo previamente descrito, obtenemos:

```
(1 * 2^0) + (0 * 2^1) + (1 * 2^2) + (0 * 2^3) + (1 * 2^4) + (1 * 2^5) = 1 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 16 + 32 = 53
```

Siendo **53** el resultado final en el **sistema decimal**.

### **Convertir del sistema numérico octal al sistema numérico decimal**

En el **sistema de numeración octal** los números se representan utilizando las cifras del **0** al **7**. Para realizar su conversión al **sistema decimal** deberá seguir estos pasos:

**1)** Debe empezar a analizar el **número octal** de derecha a izquierda y multiplicar cada dígito del **número octal** por **8** elevado a la posición que ocupa ese dígito dentro del **número octal**, donde el dígito más a la derecha ocupa la posición **0**, el segundo dígito la posición **1**, y así sucesivamente (El orden es de derecha a izquierda).

**2)** Después de realizar todas estas multiplicaciones deberá sumarlas todas y el número obtenido será el equivalente al **sistema decimal**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
237 (octal)
```

Si analizamos el número de derecha a izquierda, atendiendo al algoritmo previamente descrito, obtenemos:

```
(7 * 8^0) + (3 * 8^1) + (2 * 8^2) = 7 + 24 + 128 = 159
```

Siendo **159** el resultado final en el **sistema decimal**.

### **Convertir del sistema numérico hexadecimal al sistema numérico decimal**

En el **sistema de numeración hexadecimal** los números se representan utilizando las cifras del **0** al **9** y las letras **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E**, **F** para representar los dígitos del **10** al **15** respectivamente. Para realizar su conversión al **sistema decimal** deberá seguir estos pasos:

**1)** Debe empezar a analizar el **número hexadecimal** de derecha a izquierda y multiplicar cada dígito del **número hexadecimal** por **16** elevado a la posición que ocupa ese dígito dentro del **número hexadecimal**, donde el dígito más a la derecha ocupa la posición **0**, el segundo dígito la posición **1**, y así sucesivamente (El orden es de derecha a izquierda). Tener en cuenta que las letras **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E**, **F** deberán ser sustituidas por los números **10**, **11**, **12**, **13**, **14**, **15**.

**2)** Después de realizar todas estas multiplicaciones deberá sumarlas todas y el número obtenido será el equivalente al **sistema decimal**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
8F1 (hexadecimal)
```

Si analizamos el número de derecha a izquierda, atendiendo al algoritmo previamente descrito, obtenemos:

```
(1 * 16^0) + (15 * 16^1) + (8 * 16^2) = 1 + 240 + 2048 = 2289
```

Siendo **2289** el resultado final en el **sistema decimal**.

Una vez explicada toda la teoría anterior procedemos a explicar el código:

Declaramos la **clase SistemasNumericos** la cual posee la siguiente estructura:

**1)** **letrasPorNumeros**: Es un campo privado, estático y de solo lectura de tipo **Dictionary<char, int>**, donde la llave es un caracter y el valor asociado a esta llave será un número. Este diccionario nos servirá para hacer la conversión desde el **sistema hexadecimal** al **sistema decimal**, ya que las llaves serian las letras **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E**, **F** y los valores asociados a estas llaves serían los números **10**, **11**, **12**, **13**, **14**, **15** respectivamente.

**2)** **ConvertirBinarioToDecimal**: función estática y pública que retorna un **int** y recibe como parámetro un **string**. Esta función es la encargada de convertir un **número binario** pasado como parámetro a **número decimal**. Dentro de esta función se declaran las variables:

**potencia**: **variable de tipo int**, se inicializa en **1**, y se va duplicando a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda cada dígito del **número binario**. Esta variable se utiliza para ir convirtiendo el **número binario** a **número decimal** tal como se explica más arriba.

**numeroDecimal**: **variable de tipo int** la cual almacenará el resultado final de la conversión del **sistema binario** al **sistema decimal**. El valor que almacene esta variable será el que retornará la función.

**numeroBinario**: **variable de tipo int** que se usa para ir almacenando temporalmente cada dígito del **número binario** a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda el **número binario** pasado como parámetro a la función.

**binario**: **variable de tipo IEnumerable** que guardará el **número binario** invertido, donde cada elemento de este **IEnumerable** corresponde a un dígito del **número binario**.

Después de la declaración de la variables se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá el **número binario** invertido e irá calculando su equivalente en el **sistema numérico decimal** tal como se explicó más arriba.

**3)** **ConvertirOctalToDecimal**: función estática y pública que retorna un **int** y recibe como parámetro un **string**. Esta función es la encargada de convertir un **número octal** pasado como parámetro a **número decimal**. Dentro de esta función se declaran las variables:

**potencia**: **variable de tipo int**, se inicializa en **1**, y se va multiplicando por **8** a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda cada dígito del **número octal**. Esta variable se utiliza para ir convirtiendo el **número octal** a **número decimal** tal como se explica más arriba.

**numeroDecimal**: **variable de tipo int** la cual almacenará el resultado final de la conversión del **sistema octal** al **sistema decimal**. El valor que almacene esta variable será el que retornará la función.

**numeroOctal**: **variable de tipo int** que se usa para ir almacenando temporalmente cada dígito del **número octal** a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda el **número octal** pasado como parámetro a la función.

**octal**: **variable de tipo IEnumerable** que guardará el **número octal** invertido, donde cada elemento de este **IEnumerable** corresponde a un dígito del **número octal**.

Después de la declaración de la variables se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá el **número octal** invertido e irá calculando su equivalente en el **sistema numérico decimal** tal como se explicó más arriba.

**4)** **ConvertirHexadecimalToDecimal**: función estática y pública que retorna un **int** y recibe como parámetro un **string**. Esta función es la encargada de convertir un **número hexadecimal** pasado como parámetro a **número decimal**. Dentro de esta función se declaran las variables:

**potencia**: **variable de tipo int**, se inicializa en **1**, y se va multiplicando por **16** a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda cada dígito del **número hexadecimal**. Esta variable se utiliza para ir convirtiendo el **número hexadecimal** al **número decimal** tal como se explica más arriba.

**numeroDecimal**: **variable de tipo int** la cual almacenará el resultado final de la conversión del **sistema hexadecimal** al **sistema decimal**. El valor que almacene esta variable será el que retornará la función.

**numeroOctal**: **variable de tipo int** que se usa para ir almacenando temporalmente cada dígito del **número hexadecimal** a medida que se va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda el **número hexadecimal** pasado como parámetro a la función.

**hexadecimal**: **variable de tipo IEnumerable** que guardará el **número hexadecimal** invertido, donde cada elemento de este **IEnumerable** corresponde a un dígito del **número hexadecimal**.

Después de la declaración de la variables se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá el **número hexadecimal** invertido e irá calculando su equivalente en el **sistema numérico decimal** tal como se explicó más arriba. Tener en cuenta que si se encuentra una letra esta será sustituida por su correspondiente número utilizando para ello el diccionario que se declaró previamente.

Para utilizar la **clase SistemasNumericos** y sus funcionalidades puede hacer (Se usa una **aplicación de consola** para ejemplificar):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        Console.Write("Escriba un número en hexadecimal: ");

        //Console.Write("Escriba un número en binario: ");
        //Console.Write("Escriba un número en octal: ");

        var hexadecimal = Console.ReadLine();

        //var binario = Console.ReadLine();
        //var octal = Console.ReadLine();

        var numeroDecimal = SistemasNumericos.ConvertirHexadecimalToDecimal(hexadecimal);
        
        //var numeroDecimal = SistemasNumericos.ConvertirBinarioToDecimal(binario);
        //var numeroDecimal = SistemasNumericos.ConvertirOctalToDecimal(octal);

        Console.WriteLine(numeroDecimal);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```